# limit of an easy function. I have a interesting question

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{h\to0}{f(a+ph)-f(a-qh)\over h}$$

I know that the answer is $f'(a)\cdot (p+q)$

but, i have question. Derivative may not continuous. So that answer is right?

Comment: What denotes $$f$$ here?

Comment: "Derivative may not consecutive" doesn't mean anything.  Please try to explain a bit more.

Comment: I reformatted your post to make it more legible.  Please check that I haven't changed the meaning you intend.

Comment: @saulspatz I guess "consecutive" should be "continous". Is the answer a multiplication $f'(a)\cdot (p+q)$ ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I just came to the same conclusion myself.  I didn't notice the confusion between $q$ and $g$ though.  You must be right.

Comment: I'm not good at English. Please understand this point.

Comment: I changed "consecutive" to "continuous."  That must be what you meant to say.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

1. $f$ is differentiable at $a$,
2. $p\ne0$,
3. $q\ne0$,

your limit can be written
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\left(p\frac{f(a+ph)-f(a)}{ph}+q\frac{f(a-qh)-f(a)}{-qh}\right)=
pf'(a)+qf'(a)=(p+q)f'(a)
$$
There's no need to assume that $f'$ is continuous, it can even just exist at $a$.

Of course the formula extends also for $p=0$ or $q=0$ (or both).

If $g$ is a function for which $\lim_{h\to0}g(h)$ makes sense, then, for $r\ne0$,
$$
\lim_{h\to0}g(rh)=\lim_{k\to0}g(k)
$$
with easy $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use $$f(a+ph)-f(a-qh)=(f(a+ph)-f(a))-(f(a-qh)-f(a))$$ to write the given expression as a difference of two expressions and divide the first term by $p$ and the second by $q$ to get $f'(a)$ in both cases.